# How to Play F4V Video in HTML5 Video tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

My F4V file isn't working in the HTML5 video Player. See my code below.

```
<video class="video-js" width="415" height="205" poster="http://www.mindwork3d.com/images/poster.png" controls preload>
    <source src="http://scriptsell.net/cofique.f4v" type="video/x-f4v">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The F4V file type is not supported in the HTML5 `<video>` tag.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video or http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp for more information regarding HTML5 and the `<video>` tags and supported file types.

Comment: Thanks Do you know any better options for F4V Player .

Comment: @user3718679 Do you have an option to convert the video into an .mp4 file type? If you can convert it to .mp4 you can insert it using the <video> tag